# Angular- Always geting a 400 Bad Request response

Tags: c#, angular, rest, .net-core

I am trying to connect my frontend to my endpoint in the backend but I am always getting a 400:Bad Request response and I have no idea why. I already tested my endpoint with the same email value in Swagger and it worked perfectly fine . I can also confirm that the email I am receiving is a valid one and that its type it's string. Why is my connection not being made?

### Frontend

```
 resetPassword(email: String): Observable<any> {
    console.log("Type:" ,typeof(email));
    console.log("THE RECEIVED EMAIL IS: ", email);
    return this.http.post<any>(
      endpoint + 'User/ForgetPassword',
      JSON.stringify(email),
      httpOptions
    );
  }
```

### Backend

```
  [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("ForgetPassword")]
        public IActionResult ForgetPassword([FromBody]ForgetCredencialModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                var newPassword = _userService.GenerateRandomPassword();
                var user = _userService.UpdateCredentials(model.Email, newPassword);
                _emailService.ForgetCredencialsEmail(user.Username, newPassword, model.Email);

                return Ok(new { Message = "New Password in the email !" });
            }
            catch (AppException ex)
            {
                // return error message if there was an exception
                return BadRequest(new { message = ex.Message });
            }
        }
```

### Model

```
  public class ForgetCredencialModel
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Please show also `ForgetCredencialModel ` model

Comment: @RomanMarusyk done

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to see which one of the service is throwing the error. What is the exception message with BadRequest that you get? You can try using `ex.ToString()` to get the complete picture of the error as well (instead of just the `ex.Message`.

Comment: @Jawad this is the error I am getting
`code  error: {…}
​​
errors: Object { "$": (1) […] }
​​
status: 400
​​
title: "One or more validation errors occurred."
​​
traceId: "|3e98b69b-4efbe766cfc8b860."
​​
type: "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1"
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: lazyInit()
 }
​
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:5000/User/ForgetPassword: 400 Bad Request"
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
JSON.stringify({Email: email}));
```

because your action expect a body

```
{ "Email": "your@email" }
```

If you don't plan to extend the `ForgetCredencialModel` with other properties, then simplify it and use `JSON.stringify(email)`:

```
public IActionResult ForgetPassword([FromBody]string email)
```